# mysql insert query "Column count doesn't match value count" where as column and value both are equal

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql insert query "Column count doesn't match value count" where as column and value both are equal

Table Structure:

**Table**: role

**Columns**:

```
ID int(11) AI PK 
NAME varchar(25) 
LEVEL varchar(1) 
DESCRIPTION varchar(200) 
CREATED_DATE datetime 
CREATED_BY varchar(32) 
MODIFIED_DATE datetime 
MODIFIED_BY varchar(32)
```

my insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES 
(1,'user','T','Default role for all user','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
(2,'admin','T','System admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
(3,'super','T','Super Admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
(4,'host_user','H','Test','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
(5,'host_admin','H','Demo','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
(6,'host_super','H','again Test','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified ID AS AI(Auto-increment) primary key. When you have specified that you don't need to pass primary key in insert values.
Try removing them:

```
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES 
('user','T','Default role for all user','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
('admin','T','System admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
('super','T','Super Admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
('host_user','H','Test','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
('host_admin','H','Demo','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin'),
('host_super','H','again Test','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin','2016-09-19 08:22:34','admin');
```

Comment: I tried this but not working .I have trigger on this table when I removed this trigger its working don't know why

Comment: I fixed it the issue was related to my trigger.